# Tuple vs. Object in Swift

Tags: swift, object, tuples

I have read about the differences in Tuples and Dictionaries / Arrays, but I have yet to come across a post on Stack Overflow explaining the difference between a Tuple and an Object in Swift.

The reason I ask is that from experience, it seems that a Tuple could be interchangeable with an Object in Swift in many circumstances (especially in those where the object only holds other objects or data), but could lead to inconsistent / messy code.

In Swift, is there a time to use a Tuple and a time to use a basic Object based on performance or coding methodologies?

Comment: This is a broad question but my quick comment is that a class (or a struct) is something completely different since you can combine data and functions using that data together and you can also encapsulate the data etc, etc. That said I think that tuples are an excellent component of the Swift language and a great tool when you want to combine a few items and treat them as one in collections for instance and I use them frequently.

Comment: Apple says: *Tuples are useful for temporary groups of related values. They’re not suited to the creation of complex data structures. If your data structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As vadian notes, Apple's advice is that tuples only be used for temporary values. this plays out. If you need to do almost anything non-trivial with a data structure, including store it in a property, you probably do not want a tuple. They're very limited.

I'd avoid the term "object" in this discussion. That's a vague, descriptive term that doesn't cleanly map to any particular data structure. The correct way to think of a tuple is as being in contrast to a struct. In principle, a tuple is just an anonymous struct, but in Swift a tuple is dramatically less flexible than a struct. Most significantly, you cannot add extensions to a tuple, and adding extensions is a core part of Swift programming.

Basically, about the time you're thinking that you need to label the fields of the tuple, you probably should be using a struct instead. Types as simple as "a point" are modeled as structs, not tuples.

So when would you ever use a tuple? Consider the follow (non-existent) method on Collection:

```
extension Collection {
    func headTail() -> (Element?, SubSequence) {
        return (first, dropFirst())
    }
}
```

This is a good use of a tuple. It would be unhelpful to invent a special struct just to return this value, and callers will almost always want to destructure this anyway like:

```
let (head, tail) = list.headTail()
```

This is one thing that tuples can do that structs cannot (at least today; there is ongoing discussion of adding struct destructuring and pattern matching to Swift).

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, Tuple is a Compound Type that holds some properties together which are built up from Objects of Swift Named Types for example class, struct and enum.

I would analogize Objects of these Named Types as minerals of chemical elements ( like carbon, calcium) and Tuple is just a kind of physical mixture of these minerals( eg a pack of 1 part of calcium ore and 3 parts of carbon ore). You can easily carry around this packed tuple and add it to “heat or press” method to return “limestone” your app use in construction.

Comment: The question is about when to use a tuple vs when to use a class or struct and not about describing what a tuple is (which you do in a mildly confusing way).

Comment: Ok i could delete it if there is no help.